# Django rest framework Crear y Actualizar nested serializer/serializador anidado

Tags: djangorestframework

hace poco me tope con esta situación, como crear y actualizar mas de un objeto en una solicitud en mi API REST siendo objetos relacionados. Bueno les quiero compartir lo que aprendí. Agregue una respuesta a mi pregunta como solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Modelos**

```
class Orden(models.Model):
fecha = models.DateField()
total = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0.0)
status = models.IntegerField(default=1)    
LIST_TIPO_PAGOS = ((1,'Efectivo'), (2,'Transferencia'), (3,'Crédito'),)
tipo_pago = models.IntegerField(choices=LIST_TIPO_PAGOS, blank=False, null=False, default=1)
usuario = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='usuario')

def __str__(self):
   return str(self.fecha)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Orden'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Ordenes'

class Orden_Detalles(models.Model):
orden = models.ForeignKey(Ordenes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='orden_details')
producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='producto')
costo = models.FloatField(null=False, blank=False)
   
class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Detalle de la Orden'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Detalles de las Ordenes'
```

**Serializers**

```
"""
   ORDER DETAILS
"""
class OrdenDetalleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
producto = ProductosSerializer(read_only=True, many=False)
producto_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(write_only=True, queryset=Productos.objects.all(), source='producto')

class Meta:
    model = Orden_Detalles
    fields = ('id','producto','producto_id','costo',)

"""
   Orden Detalle Update
"""
class OrdenDetalleUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
producto = ProductosSerializer(read_only=True, many=False)
producto_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(write_only=True, queryset=Productos.objects.all(), source='producto')

class Meta:
    model = Orden_Detalles
    fields = ('id','producto','producto_id','costo',)
    extra_kwargs = {'id': {'read_only':False}}
"""
   Ordenes Create
"""
class OrdenesCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
orden_details = Orden_DetailSerializer(many=True)   

class Meta:
    model = Orden
    fields = '__all__'

def create(self, validated_data):
    #Obtener el contenido de orden_details
    orden_details_data = validated_data.pop('orden_details')
    
    #Creamos el nuevo registro de la orden
    nueva_orden = Orden.objects.create(**validated_data)
    
    #En un ciclo, recorremos el orden_detail y creamos el nuevo registro
    for orden_detail in orden_details_data:
        Orden_Details.objects.create(**orden_detail, orden=nueva_orden)       
    return nueva_orden


"""
    Orden Editar, cree un nuevo serializer para actualizar la info de Orden Detalle,
    para poder acceder al id de la orden_detalle
"""
class OrdenesUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
orden_details = OrdenDetalleUpdateSerializer(many=True)

class Meta:
    model = Ordenes
    fields = ('id','status','total',
             'tipo_pago','usuario','orden_details',)

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    # Actualizar datos de orden
    instance.total = validated_data.get('total', instance.total)
    instance.status = validated_data.get('status', instance.status)
    instance.tipo_pago = validated_data.get('tipo_pago', instance.tipo_pago)
    instance.usuario = validated_data.get('usuario', instance.usuario)
    instance.save()
    orden_details_data = validated_data.pop('orden_details')
    
    # Datos de Orden Detalles
    if orden_details_data:
        for orden_detail in orden_details_data:
            orden_detail_id = Orden_Detalles.get('id',None)
            if orden_detail_id:
                update_order_detail = Orden_Detalles.objects.get(id=orden_detail_id)
                update_order_detail.producto = orden_detail.get('aplicacion_nutricion_id',update_order_detail.aplicacion_nutricion)
                update_order_detail.costo = orden_detail.get('costo',update_order_detail.costo)
                update_order_detail.save()
            else:
                #En caso de no existir el id, crear un nuevo registro
                Orden_Detalles.objects.create(**orden_detail, orden=instance)
    else:
        # posiblemente se eliminarian en caso de existir
        pass
    
   return instance
```

**Views.py**
En las views ya cada uno agrega código conforme lo requiere, sean validaciones, permisos, etc.

```
"""
    Ordenes List y Post
"""
class OrdenesList(APIView):
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

def post(self, request):
    serializer = OrdenesCreateSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class OrdenesDetail(APIView):
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
        
def get_object(self, pk):
    try:
        return Orden.objects.get(pk=pk)  
    except Orden.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    
def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
    orden = self.get_object(pk)     
    serializer = OrdenesUpdateSerializer(orden, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
           return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
    orden = self.get_object(pk)
    orden.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```